# why the size of this struct is not correct

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof

I have this sample code which I decorated with pack to make sure that its size if 5 byte (4 for int and 1 for char).

but it print out that the size of struct is 8 byte.

```
#pragma pack push
#pragma pack 1
struct mystruct
{
    int x;
    char y;
};
#pragma pack pop

//static_assert(sizeof(mystruct) == 5, "Size of mystruct should be 5 byte.");

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int x=sizeof(mystruct);
    printf("size of struct is %d\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Why te pck is not working?

How can  make sure that size of struct is always 5.

Comment: Please read about [Padding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968468/padding-in-structures-in-c). your question already have more than 100 duplicates on SO only.

Comment: `C` or `C++`? There's a difference. Please, just pick the one you use.

Comment: @Stefan I am suing c++ on visual studio.

Comment: @mans That's one of my favourite typos ever ;-) (You'd never afford to do it though.)

Comment: And what are you trying to do with this?  Why is it a problem if the size is not 5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your pragma syntax is wrong.

Try this:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
...
#pragma pack(pop)
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/MISYC21674).

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work in all implementations

Comment: @pmg: The OP specified which implementation he's using. This is the correct approach. Using `char[N]` is frankly ridiculous.

Comment: @pmg I already tested and it should work on GNU compiler too.

Comment: @pmg Pragmas are by definition not guaranteed to work in all implementations. They give implementations implementation-specific directives.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the compiler is permitted to ignore the `pack` pragma; perhaps it can be overridden with compiler switches.

Comment: "Permitted" in what sense? The standard doesn't even define that pragma.

Comment: @Lighness Races in Orbit Well that puts it better.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can always ignore your attempts to stop packing.  This, in some ways, is a good thing, as the packing allows a higher level of efficiency...  Think of an array, when you access element 1, it is efficiently traversed to as the distance, in terms of memory, between the elements is uniform.  This is also performed with structures in order to ensure efficiency is maintained.

I direct you to this stack overflow
[Disable structure padding in C without using pragma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301759/disable-structure-padding-in-c-without-using-pragma)

Answer (score 0):

Strange- I have structs in a 3rd party program that are packed on 1-byte boundaries and they do work as expected (though not liked!).

If the compiler is ignoring your pragmas, try setting the alignment compiler options as well - C/C++ | Code Generation |  Struct Member Alignment to 1.

If the compiler is doing an "I know best" optimisation, perhaps putting the char first would stop it.